# Parse Register for Push Notification - Crash if user not signed in

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification

So i have push notifications setup and as part of the did register for push notifications i need to add the current user to the installation table. This works fine up untill there is no user signed in.

This is my code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let types:UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "user")
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}
```

I need a way of registering the user with the installation table without it crashing if there is no user on, i would do a simple check to see if there is a user signed in and then run the code if there is a user, but then if someone sent a notification to them they wouldnt get it because their PFUser.currentUser() has not been added. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking into Anonymous users (http://blog.parse.com/announcements/protect-user-data-with-new-parse-features/)? This allows you to create a PFUser for a logged out user.

This way, you can still save PFUser reference on the current installation via a PFUser.currentUser() call, but the user does not have to sign up.